# Find Enum Type from string and return enum values as List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I want to create an API which will send a enum name as string and it should return enum value as list of string.
For e.g my project contains n number of enums

```
enum WeekDays{Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday }
```

another enum could be

```
enum Colors{ Red,Green,Blue,Yellow }
```

My API call should be like this

```
List<string> GetEnumValuse(string enumName)
```

So a call could be like this `GetEnumValues("WeekDays")` which should return List of enum values.
My concern is I should use a switch...case and figure out all enums in the project, 
Instead is there a method where I could parse the string to enum and find whether there is an enum type of WeekDays or Colors so that I don't need to use switch...case.

Comment: You can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=VS.80).aspx). First, try method [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution first searchs in current namespace if enum is not found then it performs deep search within current AppDomain.

```
public Type DeepSearchType(string name)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
       return null;

    foreach (Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        foreach (Type t in a.GetTypes())
        {
            if(t.Name.ToUpper() == name.ToUpper())
               return t;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public List<string> GetEnumValues(string enumName)
{
    List<string> result = null;

    var enumType = Type.GetType(enumName);

    if(enumType == null)
       enumType = DeepSearchType(enumName);

    if(enumType != null)
    {
        result = new List<string>();

        var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(enumType);

        foreach(var val in enumValues)
            result.Add(val.ToString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the fully qualified name of you enum (i.e. namespace + class name), you can get your result like this :

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetEnumValues(string enumName)
{
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(Type.GetType(enumName)))
    {
        yield return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

which is called like that:

```
IEnumerable<string> enumValues = GetEnumValues("ConsoleApplication1.Colors");
```

Basically you get the enum values from reflection, and then return their name as a string.

You really do need the namespace (in the example, it is `ConsoleApplication1`) for the reflection to find your enum with this method, but it's by far the cleanest way I could come up with.